# How do I properly nest queries in cakephp with where clauses?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get an order from the orders table that contains a product url from the product table. I tried using this subquery but cakephp keeps reading the url value `s20_ultra` as `:c0`

```
$temp = $this->Orders->getAssociation('Product')->find()->where(['product.url' => 's20_ultra']);
$result = $this->Orders->find()->where(["productId IN" => $temp]);
echo $result;
```

Appending `firstOrFail()` to the end of the first query `temp` and commenting out the second query `result` as a test works just fine but when I append it to both I get **Cannot convert value of type %s to integer** exception.
This would be the normal query of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
select * from `order` where productId in (select product.id from product where url = 's20_ultra')
```

Comment: im not a cakephp expert, but shouldn't `$temp` contain a bunch of product ids (array of integers), i think that you're passing is an orm object. unless cakephp's api can also accept such argument, i think you need to extract the actual ids first. or might as well use an join statement instead

Comment: @Kevin `$temp` returns a query or a product object when I add `firstOrFail()` at the end of it.

Comment: You need to extract the IDs from `$temp`. What you're querying there will give you an ORM object which fetches entire entities.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you. I fixed it by passing `$temp->id` on the second where clause and calling `firstOrFail()` on both queries.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you and you're right. I needed to use `$temp->id` instead of just `$temp`.

Comment: Is there only one product that will match? If so, why are you using `IN` in the Orders where? That's for when there's multiple values. Second, why not just use standard containment? `$this->Orders->getAssociation('Product')->find()->contain(['Orders'])->where(...)`

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yeah it's for one product and I switched it to `=`. When I call get association it no longer selects from order anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said, I think that the following should work. This assumes that the associations are correctly set up in both directions between `Orders` and `Product`. (Note, that's a non-standard naming scheme, it would normally be `Products`.)

```
$product = $this->Orders->getAssociation('Product')
    ->findByUrl('s20_ultra')
    ->contain(['Orders'])
    ->firstOrFail();
debug($product->orders);
```

Comment: That query is excluding a check on product table and it's checking where order id is :c0. This is what it outputted: `SELECT Orders.id AS Orders__id, Orders.quantity AS Orders__quantity, Orders.productId AS Orders__productId FROM orders Orders WHERE Orders.product_id in (:c0)`

Comment: What does `debug($product);` give you?